# Is it possible to unpublish an InfoPath template?

Tags: microsoft-infopath

Is it possible to "Unpublish" an InfoPath template, so that the template file can be used, regardless of where the file is retrieved from?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be what you are after. The following information was found at http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/greg/archive/2004/08/11/Remove-a-Form-Template-from-the-InfoPath-Cache.aspx

> 1. Launch InfoPath.
> 2. In the Fill Out A Form dialog box, select the All Forms category.
> 3. Select the form template you want to remove from the InfoPath
>      cache.
>
> If you do not see the form template
>   listed, select All Forms from the list
>   of Form Categories at the top left of
>   the Fill Out A Form dialog box.
>
> 4. Click Remove This Form from the list of Form Tasks at the top right of
>      the dialog.
> 5. Close InfoPath.
>
> If the above steps fail and you find
>   the old for template is still loading
>   you can try one of the following:
>
> 1. Choose Run from the Start menu, type infopath /cache clearall, and
>      then click OK.
> 2. Manually delete cached InfoPath template in the cache folder located
>      at:
>
>    [Vista]: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InfoPath\FormCache2
>        [XP]: C:\Documents and Settings\\Local
>      Settings\Application
>      Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\FormCache2

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  I want the file to be useable on another user's machine (ie sent by e-mail). I may need to ask another (better thought out) question.

Comment: Would you like for me to delete the answer since you are going to rewrite your question?